# Codechef Enormous Input Test Solution

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm solving this problem on codechef https://www.codechef.com/problems/INTEST

I'm using the following code and it gives the correct answer on my system but a wrong answer when I submit. Why is that ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int n, k, ti, dv;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        scanf("%d", &ti);
        if ((ti % k) == 0)
            dv++;
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d", dv);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried it with the input given on the problem page and got the correct answer

Comment: You are using "%d" instead of "%u" for an unsigned integer... That may be the problem...

Comment: and dv is used uninitialized

Comment: dv is uninitialized.  That's the problem. Thanks

Comment: Is there any way to optimize it ?

Comment: When you have this type problem _"correct answer on my system but a wrong answer when I submit"_ use the [Codechef ide](https://www.codechef.com/ide) to find the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my Python3 solution for the problem:

```
try:
  n,k=map(int,input().split())
  count=0
  for i in range(n):
    x=int(input())
    if x%k==0:
      count+=1
  print(count)
except:
  pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Python3 solution -

```
n,k = list(map(int,input().split()))
count = 0
for _ in range(n):
    if (int(input()) % 3 == 0):
    count+=1
print(count)
```